# Declaring variables in GitLab CI yml file

Tags: gitlab-ci

I'm using value and description keywords in the variables section to create prefilled custom variables for when the pipeline runs manually. I'd also like to set some environment variables without exposing them as prefilled variables, but I keep seeing syntax errors if I try to do this:

variables:
foo: "some value"
bar:
value: "test"
description: "Enter something"

Is it not possible to mix declarations of custom prefilled variables and variables that aren't exposed? If so, what's the best way of working around this?

Answer (score 0):

Which gitlab version are you using? The feature for [prefilling variables in manual pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#variables) was introduced in 13.7.

Your code works with gitlab version 13.10:

```
stages:
  - test

variables:
 foo: "some value" 
 bar: 
   value: "test" 
   description: "Enter something"

test:
  stage: test
  script:
    - echo $foo
    - echo $bar
```

Pipeline output:

```
$ echo $foo
some value
$ echo $bar
test
```

Comment: Thanks for verifying that. We're on 13.10 so that should work. I haven't had a chance to test it out yet. I guess it's my editor (Visual Code) that might be throwing me off. When I try to write the file that way, I'm getting Incorrect type. Expected "Gitlab CI configuration". error.